# running batch file on server 2008 standard

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, windows-server

I have a simple batch file that uses Robocopy to transfer data from one of our servers to a NAS device. I have tried using both a mapped drive as well as a UNC path.

It works when I run the batch file manually (using both mapped drive and UNC) but when I use Scheduled Tasks the command window does not come up and although the task is shown as Running it just sits there and does absolutely nothing at all.

I have set up the scheduled task from the Administrator account, have "Run whether user is logged in or not" with the admin password stored.
Is also set with Run with highest privileges and under actions I have set "Start in" to the root of the D:\ drive which is where the batch file is located.

I have also checked local security policy & everything seems fine in there.

Comment: do you work in a terminal session (rdp) ? If you're in this case you will have to uncheck the "Run whether user is logged in or not" in order to see the batch execution

Comment: could you post your SCHTASKS command?

Comment: I do use RDP into the server... I unchecked Run whether user is logged in or not but that made no difference... I ran SCHTASKS and pasted the 1st part that shows the offending task (OmniNAS)        [!SCHTASKS] (http://i.imgur.com/pNCUK0T.jpg)
Please let me know if you need the full code.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Fixed it... my batch file had quotation marks in it which Server 2008 doesn't like, so I created another batch file which just calls the original batch file and it's running a treat.